# Is this "to be" a loose usage link verb?

Tags: grammar

> Listening to your speech itself is enough to be a pleasure.
>   Listening to your speech itself is enough to bring me a pleasure. (self-made)

I wonder which one is better. The first “to be” might be vague. Also we should avoid the use of “be”, if it is not necessary, right?

Comment: Both are poor composition. But that's a point besides.

Comment: _Pleasure_ is a mass noun and shouldn't have an article. The two sentences are not comparable, and therefore neither can be "better". Get better at talking before you worry about abstract clause comparison.

Comment: Unarguably mass in OP's second (mis)usage. However, pleasure, with mass and count usages, shows some variable behaviour: Walking brings me great pleasure. / The graceful skaters were a pleasure to watch. / His one pleasure was reading stories by Rudyard Kipling. / ??His six pleasures were ... What is acceptable isn't perhaps as obvious as one might hope.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with 'to be' in general, except that in the original sentence it is superfluous.

There are other criticisms to make of that sentence too. For example, the verb 'is' should surely be 'was', unless the speech is still going on, which must be unlikely.

Some of these problems carry over into your alternative.

Were it me, I would say:

'Listening to your speech was pleasure enough'.